# Gridview and MouseArea inside conflict

Tags: qt, gridview, qml, mouse

I have code like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 500
    height: 500

    GridView {
        id: grid
        anchors.fill: parent
        cellWidth: 30
        cellHeight: 30
        model: 120
        delegate: Rectangle {
            width: grid.cellWidth
            height: grid.cellHeight
            color: "grey"
        }

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onPressed: console.info(">> PRESSED triggered")
            onMouseXChanged: console.info(">> " + mouseX)
            onReleased: console.info(">> RELEASED triggered")
            preventStealing: true
            propagateComposedEvents: true
        }
    }
}
```

When I hold mouse button down and move it strictly along X axis, all the signals in `MouseArea`  trigger. But when the mouse is also moved up or down, along Y axis, the `onMouseXChanged` and `onReleased` signals do not trigger. It seems that `GridView` intercepts `MouseArea`'s signals, stealing them from the `MouseArea`. How can I make them work together: `GridView` with `MouseArea` inside?

Answer (score 0):

Set [preventStealing](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-mousearea.html#preventStealing-prop) to `true` in your `MouseArea`.

> This property holds whether the mouse events may be stolen from this MouseArea.
>
> If a MouseArea is placed within an item that filters child mouse events, such as Flickable, the mouse events may be stolen from the MouseArea if a gesture is recognized by the parent item, e.g. a flick gesture. If preventStealing is set to true, no item will steal the mouse events.

Comment: You didn't mention that as a requirement in your question.

Comment: Why not using the drag approach as shown in my example to the previous question? You don't need the `mouseX` property for that and sidebar, flicking and `MouseArea`s priorities work as expected.